# Copied jetty instance use same mysql connection pool?

Tags: hibernate

I have developed a web application in which we are using hibernate database connection pooling. Where configured max pool size as 20.

I have copied a jetty instance. Make appropriate changes into jetty.xml file.

After staring both jetty sever it get observed that when database connection exceeds 20, application take time to send response to request.

As per my understanding due to copying the jetty instance, both jetty share same connection pool.

Is the correct? If yes the what changes do i need to do in jetty configuration.

Early response are highly applicable.

Regards,
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

If there are two different jvm instances (jetty-servers) they cannot share the same connection pool.